# Using cython to convert an existing C++ function that takes std::vector and output std::vector

Tags: c++, cython, stdvector

I have a C++ file that takes std::vector and output std::vector, how do I convert it in cython ?

C++ file: cpp_func.cpp

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> my_cpp_function ( const size_t& p_num                                                    
                                                , const std::vector<float>& x
                                                , const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& table)
{
// Do some heavy calculation & and return a 2D vector called H
    return H;
}
```

Cython file:  cython_v1.pyx

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "cpp_func.h":
    vector[ vector[float] ] my_cpp_function ( size_t &p_num                                                                                 
                                            , vector[float] &x                                                     
                                            , vector[ vector[float] ] &table)
   
@cython.boundscheck(False)      
@cython.wraparound (False)      
cpdef float [:,::1] my_cython_func ( size_t p_num, float [:] x, float [:,:] table ):    
    # I have no clue here but basically what is wanted is to use
    # the above imported function to do stuff and output as memoryview
    H = my_cpp_function (p_num, x, table ) 
    return H
```

in my python file

```
import numpy as np
from cython_v1 import my_cython_func

# somewhere here, build the x and table and p_num

H = np.asarray(  my_cython_func(p_num, x, table) )

# H can be used in subsequent cheaper calculation all in python
```

Problem

1. I don't know x & table are created in numpy if they can be used by the cpp function inside cython
2. I don't know how to turn the 2D vector from cpp function into memory slice
3. Would be good if all this can be done fast and not involved copying from cpp vector to numpy/memoryview.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: what's a `memory slice`? Python has a `slice` class.  And slices can be used to index a numpy array, and the result may be a `view` of that array.  But neither python or numpy uses the term `memory slice`.

Comment: Sorry, I remember wrong name. corrected to memoryview

Comment: Yes that is a well define python concept.  Cython also has typed memoryviews, which I assume are the same (but don't quote on that). I'm not an expert on either.

Comment: Please do not use `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` : it is inefficient (both in time and memory usage) and make things more complicated. If you want a matrix, then please use a flatten array or even a dedicated library (eg. Eigen). If you want a jagged array that is never resized, then the same thing applies : flatten it.